# Arranging dissimilar sized pgfplots in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to arrange 5 plots so that the first four (equal-sized) are aligned in a 2x2 matrix, and the last one is bigger and is placed. I tried to use the `matrix` command by changing the width of the plots, but the spacing between the first 4 plots is too high. Basically I need to make the 2x2 plots independent from the last one, but the latter has to be centered with respect to the 2x2 block. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (functions){
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth]
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \end{axis}
    & & 
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth]
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \end{axis}
    \\
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth]
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \end{axis}
    & & 
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth]
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \end{axis}
    \\
    &
    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth]
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \end{axis}
     & \\
    };

\node[below] at (functions.south) {Functions};%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Think of the plots as words in a parargraph. `\centering`, `\hfil` and \\ will spread them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pfplots has a library for that: `groupplots`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=my plots]
   \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},
   height=0.45\textwidth,width=0.45\textwidth]
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot +[] { x};
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot +[] { x};
   \end{groupplot}
   \end{scope}
   \begin{axis}[anchor=north,name=functions,at={(my plots.south)},
    yshift=-1em,width=0.45\textwidth]
      \addplot +[] { x};
   \end{axis}
\node[below,yshift=-2em] at (functions.south) {Functions};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]